# Selecting one cell overwrites text in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select one cell and change the text in another cell.

For example:

When **cell.A1** is selected **cell.B1**'s text is **"hello"**
When **cell.A2** is selected **cell.B1**'s text is **"goodbye"**

Is this achievable with Visual Basic for Applications in Excel?

Thanks!

Comment: Q: Is it achievable? A: Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in your worksheet objects code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("B1").Value2 = "hello"
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("B1").Value2 = "goodbye"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would do what you need.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Address Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Hello"
    Else
        If Target.Address = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Address Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Goodbye"
        End If
End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively you could use the Case statement rather than if-else (By suggestion of T.J.L.)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Target.Address
    Case Range("A1").Address
    Range("B1").Value = "Hello"
        Case Range("$A$2").Address
        Range("B1").Value = "Goodbye"
    Case Else
        Range("B1").Value = "Wrong cell selected"
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: In one place you use `.Address`, in another you don't. This could also benefit from `select case` instead of `if-then-elseif`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I like learning how to improve my excel skills. It's indeed sloppy to only use `.address` once, and I've never used `select case` before. I'll read up and probably improve my answer.